# '!!' operator is the same as '!' in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, operators

I have seen that typescript often modify the original JavaScript operators to create their own operators.
Why does this really happen?

The same doubt I have with the operator "or logical assignment '|'"

Comment: There is no `!!` operator. That's two applications of the `!` operator. Doing that converts a value of any type to a boolean according to the normal JavaScript "truthy/falsy" rules.

Comment: What Pointy said. `||`, on the other hand, is a different operator from `|`.

Comment: @Pointy [to add more reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript)

Comment: @George oh thanks, I was looking for that. However because of the `|` vs `||` question it's more like a duplicate of two different bugs.

Comment: *"I have seen that typescript often modify the original JavaScript operators to create their own operators."* I don't think TypeScript has any operators of its own other than `<>` and `as` for casting.

Comment: @Pointy yeah I thought that as well, otherwise it'd be a close flag from me.

Comment: Typescript does add a final `!`, used to indicate an otherwise nullable value is not null, but no `!!` operator.

Answer (score 1):

> '!!' operator is the same as '!' in TypeScript?

No. There is no `!!` operator.

`!!` is just two JavaScript `!` operators in sequence.

> The same doubt I have with the operator "or logical assignment '|'"

There is `|` called Bitwise OR : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_OR

There is `||` called Logical OR : 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR

Again they are the same as JavaScript